# List all the file names from a folder and write out to a txt file keeping the special characters using cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to write out file names from a folder (subfolder) to txt but i also need to keep the special characters like for example: öüóőúéáű (hungarian) as well.
I 've tried this:

```
dir /s /b > filenames.txt
```

but it is not work this time. Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Play around with [code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepage): [`chcp`](https://ss64.com/nt/chap.html)`1250`, `chcp 254`, `chcp 320`,…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch can did the trick using the code page `chcp 65001` :

```
@echo off
chcp 65001>nul
dir /s /b>filenames.txt
start "" /MAX filenames.txt
```

Comment: Please note Miklos Padar, the codepage for the Hungarian language characters, is the Central European Latin 2 script, referred to as 852. I would therefore advise, instead of using codepage 65001, _(unsupported UTF-8)_, i.e. `chcp 65001>nul`, that you use `%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com 852 1>NUL`.